# kafka streaming reading all data in the first batch itself

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have inserted 50 records in Kafka topic with 1 second latency between each record, so 50 records in 50+ seconds.

While consuming the records from this topic, as you can see in below code, i am keeping the batch interval to 1 second. So ideally i should be getting ~50 RDDs.
I am using foreachRDD to get the data in batches , and then process data for each RDD.
In below code, each time "call" method is called, i am counting records in each RDD. The surprising thing is that the first RDD itself is showing 50 records , and obviously subsequent RDD are showing 0 records. 
I don't understand this behaviour, it should be ideally 1 record per RDD.

Can anyone suggest if my understanding is wrong?

JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));

```
messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<K, String>>>() {
            public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> rdd) {
                System.out.println("NUmber of elements in RDD : "+ rdd.count());

                List<Row> rows = rdd.map(record -> processData(record))
                        .reduce((rows1, rows2) -> {
                            rows1.addAll(rows2);
                            return rows1;
                        });

                StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
                Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
                ds.createOrReplaceTempView("trades");                
                ds.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you run the producer and the streaming application concurrently? Or has the producer already sent all the data when your streaming app starts? Looks like the latter is happening.

Comment: you are right, this is happening one by one and not concurrently.
But whats the logic behind this?

Comment: Isn't the batch interval used for the time at which the records landed in the topic?

Comment: no. Spark streaming uses "micro batching" that is, during the 'batch interval' data arrives or is collected. At each batch interval deadline, the data that arrived up to that moment is sent for processing to Spark. If when the streaming process starts, all data has already been received on Kafka, all that data will be processed at once in the first interval. New data arriving after that moment will be processes in further intervals.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of spark what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of spark what you are seeing. Had you started your streaming job and then populated the Kafka topic with data (Say 1 record every second) your batch size would have been according to your expectation. (Not quite... Because of Kafka topic partitions)

But it is possible to achieve what you want by using a spark streaming parameter called `max.rate.per.partition`

You have to keep in mind that it works per Kafka partition.

Example:

So if your Kafka topic has 3 partitions. And your `batch size is 1 second`. and `max.rate.per.partition = 1`

In the below mentioned configuration will get 3 items per RDD batch.

Sample Streaming Context:

````
```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().
    set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition",
        inputParam.maxRatePerPartition)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, inputParam.batchDuration)
```
````

If your Kafka topic has 1 partition then you will get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thnks Manas, this is helpful

Comment: It this answer is helpful can you please go ahead and accept this as answer. Always excited for more points.

Comment: the intention of `max.rate.per.partition` is to cap the amount of data that spark can request from kafka. It's meant to serve as a safety measure to avoid overload in case of cold start or peaks in the stream. Although it will do the trick, I wouldn't advise setting that to 1 to simulate a message flow as it could be misleading to persons that are starting to get familiar with the technology. I would rather advise keeping a producer running and observe the normal spark streaming behavior.

Comment: It is a very standard practise to use ```max.rate.per.partition```.  I have used this parameter to create pipe line that processes multi-million messages a day. Apart from the fact that it provides predictability to the pipeline there is no other smart way to back-fill the data. Depending upon what one does it spark application it is very easy to get OOM if the input is not throttled. This is my opinion though I respect the opinion of those who disagree.

Comment: @Manas I totally agree with your argument. `max.rate.per.partition` is a good practice.  My point is that the OP is trying to understand how Spark Streaming works with Kafka and why all data is consumed at the start. Those are basic concepts needed to build up further understanding.  Answering "you need to set rate control" to get the behavior you want is like saying "you need to tune the engine throttle" to somebody who's learning to drive. They first would need to learn about the accelerator, the steering, and the breaks. I hope I make my point. The concept is good, but maybe not for this q.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Streaming uses "micro batching" that is, during the `batch interval` data arrives or is collected.

At each batch interval deadline, the data that arrived up to that moment is sent for processing to Spark. If when the streaming process starts, all data has already been received on Kafka, all that data will be processed at once in the first interval.

[image]

Eventual new data arriving after that moment will be processes in further intervals.

Comment: See also this presentation where I explain the scheduling (and the image above): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxsOjJnwcKQ